# Find the condition on x, y and z for $span{(2, 1, 1), (1, -1, 1), (x, y, z)} = R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given that $$span{(2, 1, 1), (1, -1, 1), (x, y, z)} = R^3$$
find the condition of x, y and z that satisfies the above.

After converting it to matrix form, we get
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  2&1&x&x\\
  1&-1&y&y\\
  1&1&z&z
\end{array}
\right] $$

After a series of elementary row operation, I derive at:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0&y/2+z/2&y/2+z/2\\
  0&1&z/2 - y/2&z/2-y/2\\
  0&0&x-3z/2-y/2&x-3z/2-y/2
\end{array}
\right] $$

However, I am unsure of how to proceed after this, may I get some help after this step?

Comment: The last row must be nonzero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your augmented matrix appears to be incorrect.

Here's a slightly different way:  if $\begin{vmatrix}2&1&x\\1&-1&y\\1&1&z\end{vmatrix}\not=0$, then the columns will be linearly independent and span $\mathbb R^3$.

So, $\begin{vmatrix}1&x\\-1&y\end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}2&x\\1&y\end{vmatrix}+z\cdot\begin{vmatrix}2&1\\1&-1\end{vmatrix}=y+x-(2y-x)+z(-3)=2x-y-3z\not=0$.